# why am i not getting 1 as no of online users?

Tags: javascript

Why is the user online status is always coming `undefined` in the following:

```js
function countOnline(usersObj) {
  
  var c=0;
  for(let user in usersObj){ 
    console.log([user]['online']);
    if ([user]['online']==true){c++}
  }
  return c 
}

debugger;

countOnline({ 
  Alan: { online: false }, 
  Jeff: { online: true }, 
  Sarah: { online: false } 
});
```

Comment: `[user]` should be `usersObj[user]`

Comment: `[user]['online']` needs to be `usersObj[user]['online']`.

Comment: @Barmar can you explain why so because if i do console.log(user) it shows correct users one at time(Alan,Jeff,Sarah),,,then why user[online] wont work.

Comment: `user` is a string like `"Alan"`. `[user]` is an array containing that string. It's not the value of `usersObj["Alan"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop only iterates over the property names of your object (`Alan`, `Jeff`, `Sarah`). As you perform each iteration, you can access the property name, but you then have to pass that name as an index into the object in order to extract the value of that property within that object.

So, you have to pass the `user` variable into the `usersObj` object. For example: `obj["Alan"]["online"]` would return `false`. But your code is essentially trying to do just `["Alan"]["online"]` and that does not return anything because it's not specifying the object to look in, so it ultimately attempt to find it in the `window` object (which is the Global object in a browser) and since `window.Alan` doesn't exist, you get `undefined`.

And, since your function has a `return` in it, if you want that value, you have to be prepared to capture it when  you call the function.

```js
function countOnline(usersObj) {
  var c = 0;
  for(let user in usersObj){ 
    console.log(usersObj[user]['online']);
    if (usersObj[user]['online']==true){ c++; }
  }
  return c; 
}

debugger;

console.log(countOnline({ 
  Alan: { online: false }, 
  Jeff: { online: true }, 
  Sarah: { online: false } 
}));
```

Comment: You need to fix the `if` statement as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is because user is the key of the object it should be like this

```
for(let user in obj) console.log(obj[user]['online'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution of your code.

First your are using bracket notations to access the object which is the best practice, and you are using the for in loop and retrieving key of the object, double check it with **console.log(user)** . you got the key but to access the value of that key and as it is an Object you need to do **usersObj[user]['online']** and it will give you the value of true or false depends on the given object

**Check the full solution below**

```js
function countOnline(usersObj) {
  var c=0;

  for(let user in usersObj){
  console.log(usersObj[user]);

    if (usersObj[user]['online']===true){
    c++
  }
    } return c

};
```

Comment: *which is the best practice* <-- It's a practice. Nothing wrong with it, but hardly a best practice. It's needed when you want to pass a dynamic string into an object.

Comment: Welcome and keep it up :D

Comment: yes for sure @scottMacrus , but there are programmers who uses dot notation rather than bracket notation and it would affect later on without even knowing that the issue is from the notation way itself.